# What is this shrub with 5-petal fragrant flowers?

Tags: identification, shrubs, perennials

I have seen this shrub in mid April in a park in Western Germany and I remember the flowers were quite fragrant.

Do you know what it is?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Viburnum farreri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_farreri)* - one of the few non-white viburnums. Robust shrub originally from China, but planted in gardens all over the world.

The main blooming time is April/May, but often first flowers open during late fall and winter, when the branches are bare. (Can be confusing when searching for images.)